# How to install engine membership plugin in refinery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, refinerycms

I've tried to install the membership engine through Gemfile, after creating the refinery project, I've just added

```
gem "refinerycms_membership", :git => "git://github.com/rbriank/refinerycms_membership.git"
```

but it doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Anyone help...

Answer (score 0):

Look for new generator (rails g).